# Changing style when moving to another anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-freelancer/

Just as shown in this example, I want to give a background-color on each menu text as I move to each anchor. I prefer to this without bootstrap and only with regular javascript.

My idea was to add a function that looks like

```
function changeColor() {
    if (window.scrollY == sectionClass.offsetTop) {
    document.querySelector('.sectionClass').classList.add("newColorClass");
} else {
    document.querySelector('.sectionClass').classList.remove("newColorClass");
    }
}
```

which adds a class that has a background-color style to the element when the scroll position is on the position of the section's offsetTop.

But this doesn't seem to work as I intended.

Any idea?

Comment: can you use jQuery?

Comment: nope I cannot .

Answer (score 0):

These are classes..not anchor.
If you want it to detect anchors, they need to be #.

But more importantly, `sectionClass.offsetTop`, is sectionClass defined as a variable anywhere? Try

`window.scrollY == document.querySelector('.sectionClass').offsetTop`

Note, this will not work for "each class", it probably will only work for the first one. You'd need to make a loop for each querySelector

Comment: Yeah it is declared.

Comment: Alright, also this might help you: https://gist.github.com/jjmu15/8646226